# Right alignment in a custom dialogue environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments, dialogue

I took this `newenvironment` code from a different question here at tex.stackexchange. It works well but I would like to distinguish the dialogue partners by either left or right aligning the `\item`.

```
\newenvironment{dialogue}{\list{}{\itemsep=\parskip \topsep=\parskip \parsep=\parskip}}{\endlist}
```

Several resources online mention `\rightmargin` to adjust the horizontal distance to the right margin. Hence, I added `\rightmargin={various integers}pt` to my file but the list entries did not change.

Am I using the parameter incorrectly or does this not work in the environment generally?

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\newenvironment{dialogue}
 {\begin{list}{--}{
    \topsep=2pt
    \itemsep=0pt
    \parsep=0pt
    \parskip=0pt
    \labelwidth=8pt
    \leftmargin=8pt
    \rightmargin=100pt    % <--
    \itemindent=0pt
    \labelsep=2pt}
  }
 {\end{list}}
     
\begin{document}
\begin{dialogue}
\item \kant[1]
\item \kant[2]
\end{dialogue}
\end{document}
```

[image]